# How do I click a particular element in a pop up?

Tags: python, selenium

I have written the following selenium script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH= r"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.studentbeans.com/uk")
```

When I enter the website, there is a pop up that appears that asks if I'd like to accept all cookies. I would like to click yes. How do I add this onto my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have to select the cookie element using xpath or css selector then click by calling `click()` function.Remember it that you also need to make full screen using `driver.maximize_window()`

Try:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
PATH= r"C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.studentbeans.com/uk")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(4)
cookie_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the following error:

  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\Selenium\Selenium.py", line 8
    cookie_button=driver.find_element_by)xpath('//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
                                        ^
SyntaxError: unmatched ')'
[Finished in 252ms]

I'm using 'Sublime Text' to run the code.

Comment: @David Copperfield typo: I've updated

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the help. I'm new to Selenium. Is there a standardized syntax for how xpaths are written? What do the two forward slashes denote?.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the HTML, and find that element. Then copy the xpath or css selector or whatever and:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('copy xpath').click()
```